# How do I access/manipulate the output of splitCSV operator in Nextflow?

Tags: csv, groovy, split, nextflow

I use the stdout output to move data from one python script to another to avoid using file with one number in it. As a result I pass my information in csv string ie [data_val1, data_val2, etc...]. That works fine but I need to be able to launch two separate channels with this information. That can be accomplished with branch. My problem is handling the output of the splitCsv operator.

```
extracted_values
    .splitCsv()
    .branch{
            meta_data: new Tuple(it[0],it[1])
            other_data: it[2]
    }
    .set{script_output}

script_output.meta_data.view({"medata data is $it"})
script_output.other_data.view({"original height is $it"})
```

The documentation is very short on this operator. How is this data returned for subsequent manipulation? I would like to take the first few values and pass to one channel and send the rest to another. This would be trivial if I had a variable that had the array but I don't.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For nextflow newbies, i got some help from gitter

in regards to handling the variables read up on groovy closures. If nothing is listed, your variable is called **it**.

my solution for the split is as follows

```
Channel
    .from("val1,val2,val3")
    .splitCsv()
    .multiMap { it ->
        foo: [it[0],it[1]]
        bar: [it[2]]
        }
    .set{result}

result.foo.view()
result.bar.view()
```